# Searching a Group Homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Is there a non-zero group homomorphism from the abelian group $\prod_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb Z_n$ to $\mathbb Q$?

I  thought  of the map taking $(1,1,...)$ to $1$, but could not make through. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: The trivial homomorphism.

Comment: @LeeMosher You are right! I edited the question to "non-zero group homomorphism".

Comment: There is no "1" in $\mathbb Z_1 =\{0\}$

Comment: Yes. Of course any torsion maps to zero, so such a homomorphism factors through the quotient by the torsion subgroup. But now the element with support at all primes and nonzero coefficients all 1 represents a divisible element in the quotient. Thus the quotient has a subgroup isomorphic to the rationals, and this splits off by divisibility. Sorry for lack of detail- on phone.

Answer (score -1):

No there isn't. The image of any finite subgroup must be $\{0\}$, which is the only finite subgroup of rationals, because the image of a finite group must be finite. So there's only the zero  homomorphism

Comment: Your answer would work if the question was about the direct sum $\Sigma_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb{Z}_n$, but it's not, it's about the direct product.